# Python (qpython) socket programming

Tags: python, sockets, qpython3

```
import socket
import sys

# creating socket object
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = 'www.google.com'
port = "80"


x = "GET  /  HTTP/1.1\r\nHost :  "+ host + "\n\n"

s.connect((host, port)
s.send(request.encode()) # the line has error invalid syntax 

response  = s.recv(4096)

print (response)
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and format your code nicely

Comment: _Look at your code_. At all of your code, line by line. Do you see any syntax errors? I can see a syntax error right away. Look at _all of your code_, line by line. Python sometimes isn't terribly accurate about the line with the syntax error, but its devs surely have their reasons to make it behave like that.

Comment: Downvoted because this is just a title claiming that something unspecified is wrong and a code dump. Please describe clearly what kind of problems you have.

Answer (score 0):

Error in this line:

```
s.send(request.encode()) # the line has error invalid syntax
```

Reason:
 you have defined request with variable name `x` so this should work for you,

```
s.send(x)
```

Comment: That's the second error.  the first is it is missing a `)` on the previous line.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the existing answer about the problems with your code:

> ```
> x = "GET  /  HTTP/1.1\r\nHost :  "+ host + "\n\n"
> ```

You are trying to construct a HTTP request here but get it wrong:

1. there should be no space after `Host`, i.e. it should be `Host: hostname` and not `Host: hostname` as you do.
2. The end of line should be `\r\n` and not `\n`. You get it right after the first line but not after the `Host` header and not for the end-of-header marker.